# How can i convert value to time using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, time

I am using **Ionic Timepicker**. When I select a time it's passing values like  `75600` (here I have selected **09:00pm**). How to actually retrieve a human readable string instead of an "epoch time" value?

Here's my code:

```
    $scope.timePickerObject12Hour.inputEpochTime = val;
    console.log(val);
    // here i am getting 79200
    var selectedTime = new Date();
    var amPmHour = $filter('date')(selectedTime, 'hh');
    console.log(amPmHour);
    // here i am getting 07
    console.log('Selected epoch is : ', val, 'and the time is ', selectedTime.getUTCHours(), ':', selectedTime.getUTCMinutes(), 'in UTC');
    //here i am getting Selected epoch is :  75600 and the time is  16 : 5 in UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using the **plain Javascript `Date`** object:

```
new Date($scope.timePickerObject12Hour.inputEpochTime*1000);
```

Don't forget to **multiply** the *"epoch time"* value you get from *Ionic Timepicker* by 1000, since the **Javascript Date constructor** takes a number of **milliseconds**, not seconds.

in your case, the following code:

```
console.log($filter('date')(new Date(79200*1000), 'hh:mma'));
```

... would output:

```
09:00PM
```

---

Here's a working [JSFiddle (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/3f1ewwm8/1/) that will feature a working example using the tools you're working with.

Comment: controller i am getting value like that

Comment: i have follwed this https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker pls check and say ur answer

Comment: if i select 10.00pm console i am getting 3.30pm it not working correct

Comment: check your jsfiddle code it's showing 3.30 instead of 9.00pm